# using two MIDlets in a J2ME application

Tags: java-me, netbeans-6.9, midlet

I am designing a j2me mobile application. In the design of the user I need to design the login page, register page and after finishing the login page i need to show the available records to the authorized user. can we use two or more MIDlets for this type of application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use single MIDLET. Withing single midlet you can have mulitple classes with (lwuit/lcdui forms) say one form for Login and other for SignUP.
Simply use once class which extends Midlet.